# Help with Incorrect proof of Plancherel's Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series

> Plancherel's Theorem
>
> Let $f$ $\in$ $(C^{2\pi}$, $||f||_{2}$) where $||f||_{2} = \Big(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^{2}dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
>   \begin{align*}
> ||f-S_{n}(f)||_{2} \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
> \end{align*}
>   where $S_n(f)$ is the Fourier Partial Sum of $f$.

Here is my proof so far however, I know that it must be incorrect because it would imply that $S_{n}(f)$ would converge uniformly to $f$ in the Sup norm. Note that $T_{n}$ is the set of Trig polynomials of degree at most $n$.

\begin{align*}
|| f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2} &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x) - S_{n}
(f)(x)|^{2}dx \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2}dx \\
&= ||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx \\
&= ||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi \\
&= ||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2} \\
&\leq ||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2} \\
\end{align*}

Hence, 
\begin{align*}
|| f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2} \leq ||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2} \\
\end{align*}

By Weierstrass's 2nd Approximation Theorem,

\begin{align*}
||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2} \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \implies || f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2} \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{align*}

However, this would also imply (with respect to the Sup norm)

\begin{align*}
||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2} \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \implies ||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2} \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{align*}

And I know this to be incorrect for any $f\in C^{2\pi}$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the last implication. There is no inequality above it which gives $\|.\|_{\infty}$ convergence.

Comment: $||f - S_{n}(f)||_{2}^{2}$ $\leq$ $||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2}$ $\leq$ $||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2}$ $\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

Comment: The second inequlaity is not correct. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Well, I thought $||f - S_{n}(f)||_{\infty}^{2}$ $\leq$ $||f - T_{n}||_{\infty}^{2}$ because $S_{n}(f) \in T_{n}$. Where $S_n(f)$ is the Fourier Partial Sum of $f$ and $T_{n}$ is the set of trig polynomials of at most degree $n$.

Comment: This argument is not valid. It is true that $S_n(f)$ is a trigonometric polynomial but it is not true that $\|f-S_n(f)\|_{\infty}$ is the least among all trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: I see, thank you @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92529/discussion-between-matthieu-and-kavi-rama-murthy).